# Spark UDF with Map as input

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am creating a UDF as follows:

```
UserDefinedFunction userDefinedFunction = functions.udf(String value, Map<String, Integer> map) -> {
      return map.get(value)
    }, DataTypes.IntegerType
);
```

I have a `java.util.Map<String, Integer>` that I need to pass into this function:

```
    Dataset<Row> newDataset = oldDataset.withColumn("newColumn",
      userDefinedFunction.apply(
        col("valueColumnName"), <<pass java map here>>);
```

How do I pass this `java.util.Map` into the UDF?

I tried converting Java Map to Scala Map, but `typedLit` is throwing the following exception:

`Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2 Map(...)`

Comment: I suggested a solution but I'm not sure that's what you want to do

Comment: This is a question about using Spark from Java. I think the only responder missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options use the spark.sql.function map_values which extracts values of Map into an array or use the udf.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#map_values-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-

for the udf, you can do it like that, here I extract the values coressponding to the key "hello" of the Map:

```
val df1  = Seq(
  ("1", Map("hello" -> "firas")),
  ("1", Map("hello2" -> "moadh", "hello" -> "firas2"))
).toDF("id", "map")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
def mapUdf(value: String)  = udf((map1: Map[String, String]) => map1(value))
df1.withColumn("mapValue", mapUdf(("hello"))(col("map")))



I get this:
+---+---------------------------------+---------
| id|                 map             |mapValue|
+---+---------------------------------+---------
|  1|    [hello -> firas]             |   firas|
|  1|[hello2 -> moadh,hello -> firas2]|  firas2|
+---+---------------------------------+---------
```

Comment: I Need to look up external map for column value

Comment: any advice on this UDF issue plz   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935600/writing-udf-for-looks-up-in-the-map-in-java-giving-unsupported-literal-type-clas